# Codeigniter, Undefined variable without $data

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

salam, I'm having a problem with a variable that is undefined in view. I don't use a `$data` variable in the controller before. after I use the `$data`, it still remains doesn't appear in my view (called dashboard). Can someone help me to solve this code?

I'm sorry, I know there are questions like this before. but I want to know mine, what is the problem, besides my code in another file are fine

home.php as controller

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->loginstatus->check_login();
    $this->load->library('template');
    $this->load->model('day_off_model');
}

public function index(){
    redirect('home/info');
}

public function info(){
    $data = array();
    $data['ym'] = date('Y-m');
    $this->template->display('information/dashboard');

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

    //$data['harian'] = 'a';
    // Get prev & next month
    if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
        $ym = $_GET['ym'];
    } else {
        // Bulan ini
        $ym = date('Y-m');
    }
    //echo $ym;

    // Check format
    $timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
    if ($timestamp === false) {
        $timestamp = time();
    }

    // Today
    $today = date('Y-m-j', time());

    // H3 title
    $html_title = date('m Y', $timestamp);

    $parts =  explode(' ',$html_title);
    $date   = $parts[0].' '.$parts[1];

    // return $date;
    // print_r($html_title);
    // die();

    $html_title=$this->tanggal->tanggal_indo_month_yeartext($date);

    // print_r($html_title);
    // die();

    // link prev next     mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year)
    $prev = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)-1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
    $next = date('Y-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp)+1, 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));

    // Jumlah hari seblan
    $day_count = date('t', $timestamp);

    // 0:Minggu 1:Senin 2:Selasa ...
    $str = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1, date('Y', $timestamp)));
    //$str = date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $timestamp), 1, date('Y', $timestamp))); //senin, selasa, rabu

    // Create Calendar
    $weeks = array();
    $week = '';

    // cell dengan tabel kalender
    $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str);
    //$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str-1);

    for ( $day = 1; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {

        $date = $ym.'-'.$day;
        $exist = $this->day_off_model->get_all(false)->num_rows();
        // print_r($exist);
        // die();
        if ($today == $date) {
            $week .= '<td class="today">'.$day;
        } else {
            $week .= '<td>'.$day;
        }
        $week .= '</td>';

        // End of the week OR End of the month
        if ($str % 7 == 6 || $day == $day_count) {
        //if ($str % 7 == 0 || $day == $day_count) {
            if($day == $day_count) {
                // empty cell
                $week .= str_repeat('<td class="column_custom"></td>', 6 - ($str % 7));
                //$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 7 - ($str % 7));
            }

            $weeks[] = '<tr>'.$week.'</tr>';

            // weeks
            $week = '';
        }
    }
    //redirect('home/info');
}
```

dashboard.php as view

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('user_type_id')==TRUE){?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Sistem Informasi Absensi Kepegawaian</h1>
    <hr/>
    Informasi terbaru Absensi Kepegawaian<br/>
    Pascasarjana Universitas Diponegoro
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php echo $ym; ?>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h3><a href="?ym=<?php echo $prev; ?>">&lt;</a><?php echo $html_title; ?> <a href="?ym=<?php echo $next; ?>">&gt;</a></h3>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered dashboard">
        <tr>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Minggu</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Senin</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Selasa</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Rabu</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Kamis</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Jum'at</th>
            <th class="th_custom" width="30px">Sabtu</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($weeks as $week) {
                echo $week;
            }   
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<?php }
else{?>
<h3>Silahkan login sebagai admin terlebih dahulu</h3>
<?php }?>
```

I'm curious about `$ym` too. variable `$prev`, `$html_title` and `$next` are not identified. Should I pass this code?

thank you

Comment: What do your routes look like? Instead of redirecting, you should load a view and pass the variables in there. Have a look at this documentation for dynamically adding data to a view: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: I'm using home as default
    $route['default_controller'] = "home";
    $route['404_override'] = '';
    $route['translate_url_dashes'] = true;

Comment: So it looks like from your `info` method you need to load a view instead of redirecting. Like this: `$this->load->view('home/info', $data);`. You need to group up all of the data you wish to pass to the view into a single array. Also, in your `index` method instead of redirecting, maybe just do `return $this->info();`

Comment: it occurs an error
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: home/info.php

Comment: Make sure that your view file is in the correct directory: `application/views/home/info.php`. You would create a folder for your class, and a view file for each method.

Comment: I use most $data variable due to this file won't load on view XD. you help a lot. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this sort of structure:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // load other stuff
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->info();
    }

    public function info()
    {
        $data = [];

        // group all data you wish to pass to the view inside the $data array in this format:
        // $data[<variableName>] = <variableValue>

        $this->load->view('myView', $data);
    }
}
```

All of your variables that you want available inside the view need to be defined as a key in the array that you pass, in this case `$data`:

```
$data['myVar'] = 'myValue'
```

Will correspond to the following in the view:

```
var_dump($myVar); // result: myValue
```

You can do the same with arrays that you want to pass:

```
$data['myArray'] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

And access it in the view as follows:

```
var_dump($myArray); // result: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: this is incredibly helping my work. thank you for the debug with var_dump, I found what I miss. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**In the Controller**
**Change these lines**

```
public function info(){
    $data = array();
    $data['ym'] = date('Y-m');
    $this->template->display('information/dashboard');
```

***To***

```
public function info(){
    $data['ym'] = date('Y-m');
    $this->template->display('information/dashboard', $data);
```

**In the view file, you can echo the `ym's` value like this;**

```
echo $ym;
```

Comment: You're most welcome. Mark this as the answer, else others may bother for typing more answers